# First order differential equation - area.

Tags: integration, area

a) Solve the differential equation:

$$(x+1)\frac{dy}{dx}-3y=(x+1)^4$$

given that $y=16$ and $x=1$, expressing the answer in the form of $y=f(x)$.

b) Hence find the area enclosed by the graphs $y=f(x)$, $y=(1-x)^4$ and the $x-axis$.

-I have found the answer to part a) using the first order linear differential equation method and the answer to part a) is: $y=(1+x)^4$. However how would you calculate the area between the two graphs($y=(1-x)^4$ and $y=(1+x)^4$) and the x-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good job on solving part (a) of the question. That was the tough part. Part (b) is much more easier.

As you stated, we get that the function is:

$$y = (1+x)^4$$

Now, in order to find the area between this function, the function $f(x) = (1-x)^4$, and the $x$-axis, we need to the find intersection points:

$$(1+x)^4 = (1-x)^4$$
$$\left((1+x)^4\right)^{1/4} = \left((1-x)^4\right)^{1/4}$$
$$1+x = 1-x$$
$$x = 0$$

When $x=0$, $(0+1)^4 = (0-1)^4 = 1$. Thus, we get that the two functions intersect at the point $(0, 1)$.

Next, we look at where each of the two functions intersect the $x$-axis. We get that:
$$(1+x)^4 = 0\\ 1+x = 0\\ x = -1$$
$$(1-x)^4 = 0\\ 1-x = 0\\ x = 1$$

Therefore, we get our two endpoints: $(-1, 0)$ and $(1, 0)$.

Take a look at [the graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%20y%20%3D%20%28x%2B1%29%5E4%2C%20y%20%3D%20%28x-1%29%5E4). Note that we have to split the area into two integrals.

Thus, we can use construct our integral now:

$$A = \int_{-1}^0 (1+x)^4 dx + \int_{0}^1 (1-x)^4 dx$$

$$ \left[\frac{(x+1)^5}{5}\right]_{-1}^{0} + \left[\frac{(x-1)^5}{5}\right]_{0}^{1} = \frac{1}{5} - 0 + 0 - \left(-\frac{1}{5}\right) = \frac{2}{5}$$

Hope that helped. Comment if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

We start by finding where $(x+1)^4=0$ and $(x-1)^4=0$.

In the first case,
$$(x+1)^4=0$$
$$x+1=0$$
$$x=-1$$
In the second case,
$$(x-1)^4=0$$
$$x-1=0$$
$$x=1$$

We have to check to see if the functions intersect at any point. To do this, we write
$$(x+1)^4=(x-1)^4$$
$$(x+1)=\pm(x-1)\to x+1=x-1\text{ or }x+1=-x+1$$
The first of these two possibilities is obviously false, so the second must be true. Therefore, $2x=0$, and the functions are equal at $x=0$.

We can check all these bounds by graphing them:
[image]

<sup>Graphed using the [Desmos graphing calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator).</sup>

Therefore for half of the interval, $(x-1)^4>(x+1)^4$, and for half the interval $(x-1)^4<(x+1)^4$. We find that the first case holds for $x>0$, and the second case holds for $x<0$.

Now we have to simply break up the integral. To do this, we have to find the area under whichever function is lesser in a given interval. Therefore, using our results, we have
$$A=\int_{-1}^0(x+1)^4\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^1(x-1)^4\mathrm{d}x$$
Some $u$-substitution should give you your answer. Can you go from here?